# How is this for loop console logging the value and not the whole object?

Tags: javascript, object, iterator, generator, for-of-loop

I'm learning about generators in YDKJS and it's explaining how iterators work such as here:

```
var something = (function(){
    var nextVal;

    return {
        // needed for `for..of` loops
        [Symbol.iterator]: function(){ return this; },

        // standard iterator interface method
        next: function(){
            if (nextVal === undefined) {
                nextVal = 1;
            }
            else {
                nextVal = (3 * nextVal) + 6;
            }

            return { done:false, value:nextVal };
        }
    };
})();

something.next().value;     // 1
something.next().value;     // 9
something.next().value;     // 33
something.next().value;     // 105
```

I understand this just fine. It then demonstrates how a `for..of` loop can be used so that a standard `iterator` can automatically be consumed with native loop syntax such as this:

```
for (var v of something) {
    console.log( v );

    // don't let the loop run forever!
    if (v > 500) {
        break;
    }
}
// 1 9 33 105 321 969
```

I understand the gist of it, but how is only the `value` coming back and not the whole object including the `done: false`?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, clearly for v of is checking if its done internally and just gives you the value as it was indeed designed to be used with iterators. You can also check how babel implements it : https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-for-of/

Comment: Because that's how iterators work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Iterating_over_other_iterable_objects

Comment: [ECMAScript 2015 - 13.7.5.13 Runtime Semantics: `ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation ( lhs, stmt, iterator, lhsKind, labelSet)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset): steps 5a (`Let nextResult be IteratorStep(iterator)`) to 5d (`Let nextValue be IteratorValue(nextResult)`)